# SQL sum of two line if equal

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, prestashop

I have a table like this:

```
REFERENCE   QUANTITY
AS400        0
AS400        30000
AB123        500
CA031        560
CA031        25
```

I need to have, in sql, the total quantity if the rows are the same.
For ex:

```
AS400  30000
AB123    500
CA031    585
```

Answer (score 0):

You could using group by like below query

```
select REFERENCE, sum(QUANTITY)
from tableA
group by REFERENCE
```

Comment: The system give me this:
Impossibile valutare l'espressione "select 'AS400', sum('0')
group by 'AS400'". Errore: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select 'AS400', sum('0')
group by 'AS400'' at line 1"

I'm using emagico one prestashop if can help

Comment: You must use column name not value

Answer (score 0):

If do you want to get the quantites by reference from `ps_product_attribute`, the code which is working on Ps1.7.6 :

```
select `reference`, sum(`quantity`)
from `ps_product_attribute`
group by `reference`
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's work i think that the problem is my software: exemple to insert substring i have to insert only this SUBSTRING_INDEX([CSV_COL(41)],'\']',1) so i think that i find a solution to use your formula.